# SQl CASE Statement

Tags: t-sql

I want to sort column value(`DateTime`) on a condition(and event occurring before `March 1st 2016` as `'Preseason'`,

event Occurring after `march 31st 2016` as `'PostSeason'` Else `'Season'`.
--Query---
    Select EventDate= Case 
    When EventDate <'01-03-2016' then 'PreSeason'
    When EventDate >'31-03-2016' then 'PostSeason'
    Else 'Season' 
    End,
    EventName From tblEvent

--Error Message
 'Msg 242,The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

Comment: What you tried so for?

Comment: That error tells me that your DateTime column has non-DateTime values.  You could try CASTing it in your CASE statement, maybe?

Comment: You did not think that posting the actual statement would be of value?

Comment: Select EventDate= Case 
When EventDate <'01-01-1975' then 'PreSeason'
When EventDate >'31-12-1979' then 'PostSeason'  
Else 'Season' 
End,
EventName From tblEvent

Comment: @johnny-bones- ya, i tried Cast and Convert but the column i am working has data_type DateTime and i want to substitute that col with a new column Named 'Season' (Varchar) With, only three types of values(PreSeason, Season, PostSeason) in that col. based on the EventDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- ok, Was a date format issue.  i used a European Date Format(dd-mm-yyyy) in my query but the system i use takes USA date Format(mm-dd-yyyy) so my query failed. 
**

- Solution

**
    Select Cast(Case 
    When EventDate <='01/01/2016' then 'PreSeason'
    When EventDate >='12/31/2016' then 'PostSeason'
    Else 'Season' 
    End As Varchar(25)) as Season, EventName From tblEvent

Thanks for Support!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like..

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN ISDATE(DateTime) = 1 THEN 
    CASE DateTime
       WHEN <= '2016-03-01' THEN 1   -- Preseason
       WHEN >= '2016-03-31' THEN 3   -- PostSeason
       ELSE 2 END                    -- Season
   ELSE 4 END,                       -- Not a date, figure out how to handle
  DateTime
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer and pointing at what really i should be looking at is how to handle the data type conflict in the case statement.